# Resolvconf problem after adding a wireless interface

Tags: networking, dns

I'm having trouble with the DNS servers of a machine after adding a wireless device to it. I configured the wireless interface through the GUI Network Manager, IPv4 I've tried both DHCP and link-local with no success.

The `/etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/base` has two nameserver entries and a search domain, from my lan interface, but my `/etc/resolv.conf` only contains `nameserver 127.0.1.1` and the search domains configured in base but not its nameserver entries. Running `resolvconf -u` doesn't seem to add the base.

So whenever I try to resolv a hostname I get a connection time out:

```
nslookup www.google.com
;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached
```

Anybody could point me to the problem? I'm on "Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS", using xfce over vnc.

Comment: What "trouble" are you having exactly? Is there an actual name resolution issue, or are you just asking why your resolv.conf file isn't what you expect?

Comment: yeah, there is an actual name resolution issue: I'll edit to clarify

Comment: Well, AFAIK it's normal that the resolvconf base file is ignored when dnsmasq is used - see [resolvconf no longer honors resolv.conf.d/base](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/resolvconf/+bug/917896). IMHO the **right** way to select alternate DNS servers when using network-manager + dnsmasq is to select the "Automatic (DHCP) **addresses only**" IPv4 connection option, and set the desired DNS servers there.

Comment: but my wired connection doesn't appear in the GUI Network Manager. Should I add the connection there? I'm on remote, I don't want to loose that connection

Comment: Sorry - I have no experience of running multiple concurrent interfaces. If that's a requirement I'd suggest making it clear in your question.